# $timeout with ng-if in angular?

Tags: angularjs

I have a `ng-if` condition:

```
<div class="fixed-outside" ng-if="'app.home'|isState">
```

i.e whenever the state is `app.home` show the div.

But I want to wait for some time before my div is shown. How can I do that

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest to do it with css and add animation with delay for `.fixed-outside` class. For instance, if you need to wait for 5 seconds before revealing block, you may do something like this:

```
.fixed-outside {
  animation: 5s fadeIn;

  visibility: hidden;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  99% {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  100% {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this: In your controller make a function that returns `app.home` but instead of returning it instantly wrap it inside a `$timeout` and replace on the view `ng-if="'app.home'|isState"` for the new function.

Something like:

**controller**

```
$scope.getAppHome = function(){
    $timeout(function(){
     return home;          //or whatever var 'home' represents on the view 'app.home'
    }, 200);
}
```

**view**

```
<div class="fixed-outside" ng-if="app.getAppHome()|isState">
```

Comment: getAppHome() returns undefined.

Comment: Could you show me some minimal reproducible code of what you are trying to do? A snippet or something? I need to see you controller. How is var `home` being initialized?